# What is 0xXXXXXXXX.asc.sig and how can I generate this?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature, key-exchange, gnupg

When I am exchanging PGP keys with someone, I receive the regular 0xXXXXXXXX.asc file and regularly receive a file called 0xXXXXXXXX.asc.sig.

What is this file?
How can I generate one and send it with my .asc file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The .sig file is a detached signature. You use your key to sign a file to certify its authenticity. If the file is changed in any way, the verification process will fail and the party that received the file will know that it has been tampered with after you sent it out.

I believe the .asc.sig you received is a certificate of that guy's public key certifying its authenticity.

You can append the signature to the file itself or have it in a separate file. In this case, instead of appending the signature to the file, the signature is in a standalone file.

To sign it: `gpg -a --output doc.asc.sig --detach-sig doc`

`-a` is to create an ascii armored output
`doc.asc.sig` is the filename you want for the signature
`doc` is the filename you wish to sign

Comment: Why would someone sign his own PGP key? What is the benefits? Thanks.

Comment: Its controversial, as highlighted on this site
http://www.iusmentis.com/technology/remailers/selfsign.html

Comment: Somehow, it is a self-signature, but... self-signing usually refers to certification signatures issued by your primary key on your own user IDs, and shouldn't be a detached signature.

Comment: @user3686362: A self-signature provides proof against tampering, but not additional trust.